# How to execute a terminal command at boot

Tags: boot, command-line, resolution

What i want to do is get this custom screen resolution with xrandr to run at every boot so i don't have to enter it myself or copy and past it this is the code i want to run at every boot

```
cvt 800 600 60 && xrandr --newmode "800x600_60.00"   38.25  800 832 912 1024  600 603 607 624 -hsync +vsync && xrandr --addmode TV1 800x600_60.00 && xrandr --output TV1 --mode 800x600_60.00
```

i don't really want to play around editing configure/files just a nice easy script that will execute after or during every boot.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to execute before the login manager, just put it at the end of `/etc/rc.local`

Comment: I don't really know what i'm doing  but i added my code to /etc/rc.local saved and rebooted and it did nothing. I re-looked at it and saw that it said this script does nothing In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution bits. So how would i do that

Answer (score 0):

You can try putting your commands in `~/.profile`. This file is executed when you log in, so you should see the resolution change at that point.

I can't guarantee this method though, because I don't know if your system has other startup scripts in the home folder.

As for rc.local, it should be executable by default. If it isn't, you can `sudo nautilus` to browse as root, then right-click on the file and select "Properties". From here you can make the script executable so it will work. You can also use chmod, but I thought you would prefer this method.

One more tip: running cvt only gives you the data you need for xrandr. You can drop it.

Answer (score 0):

Neither of these places work on my Debian 12 machine, I doubt there's a truly universal place to put it.  chmod +x filename will normally make a file executable (under Bash).  I'm trying to turn off rfkill blocking on every boot.